# прикрутить xDebug к phpStorm (denwer)

Tags: phpstorm, denwer, xdebug

хочу начать с того, что денвер у меня стоял. создал папку deb.ru (внутри z:/home/ разумеется) далее добавил index.php, туда запхал пару строк кода, запустил денвер, зашел по адресу deb.ru. на этом месте все ок, работает.

далее я вывожу phpinfo, xdebug показывается (он поставляется с денвером)
в php.ini я поправил несколько переменных:

```
;указал полный путь, т.к. с относительным phpStorm работать не захотел
extension_dir = "z:/usr/local/php5/ext"

;собственно настройки xdebug
[xdebug]
zend_extension="\usr\local\php5\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9.dll"
xdebug.auto_trace = 0
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%u"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "/tmp"
```

Далее открываю скачано-установленный ДЕСЯТЫЙ phpStorm. Создаю проект указывая ранее созданный каталог z:/home/deb.ru/www. Там валяется наш index.php с парой строк кода.

Далее захожу в настройки:

Первое куда я зашел это File->Settings->Languages & Frameworks->PHP

Второе это настройки в Run->Edit Configurations

Все это вы увидите в одном большом скрине, т.к. у меня нет прав грузить много маленьких картинок.. вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

потом я перезагрузил денвер, поплясал с бубном и делал тому подобные вещи.
и самое интересное начинается здесь.

- если я нажимаю run->debug и выбираю из предлагаемого списка index.php то он запускает файл в режиме отладки
- и если я нажимаю run->debug но в списке я выбираю deb, то открывается страница в браузере по адресу deb.ru/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=19906 и сразу выдает ответ. не останавливаясь на точках

можете помочь? что я сделал не так?

Comment: Попробуй две вещи: **1)** в  шторме в верхнем правом углу нажать на телефончик (прослушка), чтоб тот стал зеленым [смотри тут](http://i017.radikal.ru/1601/d1/ccc7c11d22b9.jpg) **2)** настрой маппинг. Маршрут. То есть нужно связать путь в проекте с путем на сервере [смотри тут](http://s020.radikal.ru/i707/1601/b2/a37aa8718db3.jpg) ... Если поможет опубликую потом как ответ.... в настройках `ini` по идее еще должно быть..`xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"`

Comment: по моему второй скрин помог, ну я еще + конфиги наболтал, что ты указал. благодарствую за ответ, оч помог. почти весь день продолбался :)

Comment: Ну надеюсь поможет. Сам к шторму пытался полдня прикрутить по разным инструкциям. Конечным пунктом к достижению цели был именно маппинг.... на всякий случай опубликовал как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо попробовать две вещи:

В шторме в верхнем правом углу нажать на телефончик (прослушка), чтоб тот стал зеленым. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это должно позволять просто перезагружать страницу для подхвата брейкпойнтов.

Во-вторых необходимо настроить маппинг. Маршрут. То есть нужно связать путь в проекте с путем на сервере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файле `ini` скорее всего не хватает строчек:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1 
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp" 
xdebug.remote_host="localhost
```

Для примера приведу настройки из своего `php.ini`. Не знаю на сколько они верные, но работают для меня 100%

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="g:/! work/!WEBServers/OpenServer/modules/php/PHP-5.5/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.default_enable = 1
;эта опция  отвечает за автостарт
;xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Естественно путь `zend_extension` другой будет

Answer (score 0):

PhpStorm 2016.1.2 Сделал все вышеупомянутые настройки по дефолту кроме интерпретатора - первое изображение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зашел сюда - File->Settings->Languages & Frameworks->PHP->Debug. Находим раздел External connections. Убираем галку Break at first line in PHP scripts.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  Ставим брекпоинт. Нажимаем Listening...,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В браузере вводим свой сайт и в PhpStorm выбираем свой index.php (или что там у вас) из предложенных. Само все настраивается.