# phpStorm Xdebug как настроить маппинг?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

Настроил связку Xdebug и PHPStorm.

Как настроить корректно маппинг? Проект находится в той же папке откуда запускается на сервере. У меня сейчас вот так:

[image: маппинг]

php.ini такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сервер захожу вот так: www.uk.local

httpd.conf Такой
ServerName localhost:80

debug в phpStorm:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поможет? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480402/191482

Comment: Не помогла ни одна настройка. PhpStorm 2016.1.2 Сделал все вышеупомянутые настройки по дефолту. Зашел сюда - File->Settings->Languages & Frameworks->PHP->Debug. Находим раздел External connections. Убираем галку Break at first line in PHP scripts. Ставим брекпоинт. Нажимаем Listening..., В браузере вводим свой сайт и в PhpStorm выбираем свой index.php (или что там у вас) из предложенных. Само все настраивается.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще пхпшторм вроде остановкой на первой строке при дебаге не страдает и там даже нет такой опции, таким по дефолту точно страдал нетбинс. Как вариант у вас не настроен мап сорцов и пхпшторм там в окошке дебага об этом ненавязчиво спрашивает при начале сессии. Ну и должен работать переход до след. точки останова по F9, если не работает, то точно мапа нет.

Comment: Вообще-то, в php storm как раз есть настройка остановки на первой строчке.