# Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'

Tags: php, phpstorm, openserver, xdebug

Всем привет, настраивал xdebug получаю такую ошибку при нажатии на debug Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'
Настройки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может это поможет: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480402/191482 ?  Возможно дело в маппинге сервака.... либо на значок "телефон" не нажали

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский     [screenshot](http://joxi.ru/zAN0q63SB1Pgxm)