# xDebug настройки

Tags: php, xdebug

Как бы ни было удивительно,но не выходит настроить xDebug, прочет кучу документации и настроек,уже наверное в php.ini такого понаписывал,так как везде разные настройки вычитывал,помогите пожалуйста ибо не могу проверить на корректность проект

версия php 7.4

я сброшу настройки,может быть я все-таки где-то промахнулся

```
[xdebug]

;xdebug.auto_trace               = off
;xdebug.cli_color                = 0
;xdebug.coverage_enable          = on
xdebug.default_enable            = 1
;xdebug.extended_info            = 1
;xdebug.file_link_format         = ""
;xdebug.filename_format          = ""
;xdebug.force_display_errors     = 0
;xdebug.force_error_reporting    = 0
;xdebug.halt_level               = 0
;xdebug.idekey                   = ""
xdebug.max_nesting_level        = 20000000
;xdebug.max_stack_frames         = -1
;xdebug.overload_var_dump        = 2
; disable the @ (shut-up) operator
;xdebug.scream                   = off

;xdebug.collect_assignments      = off
;xdebug.collect_includes         = on
;xdebug.collect_params           = off
;xdebug.collect_return           = off
;xdebug.collect_vars             = off

;xdebug.dump.COOKIE              = ""
;xdebug.dump.ENV                 = ""
;xdebug.dump.FILES               = ""
;xdebug.dump.GET                 = ""
;xdebug.dump.POST                = ""
;xdebug.dump.REQUEST             = ""
;xdebug.dump.SERVER              = ""
;xdebug.dump.SESSION             = ""
;xdebug.dump_globals             = on
;xdebug.dump_once                = on
; dump undefined values from the superglobals
;xdebug.dump_undefined           = off

;xdebug.gc_stats_enable          = off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir       = "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/xdebug"
;xdebug.gc_stats_output_name     = "gcstats.%p"

; 1 - single profiler file will be written for multiple requests
;xdebug.profiler_aggregate       = 0
; 1 - append, 0 - overwrite
;xdebug.profiler_append          = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable          = 0
; XDEBUG_PROFILE as GET/POST/COOKIE parameter
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  = 1
; XDEBUG_PROFILE secret
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir       = "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name     = "cachegrind.out.%H%R"

;xdebug.remote_addr_header       = ""
xdebug.remote_autostart         = on
;xdebug.remote_connect_back      = off
;xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 3600
xdebug.remote_enable            = on
xdebug.remote_handler           = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host              = "localhost"
;xdebug.remote_log               = ""
; req - connect on every script starts, jit - connect only on error
xdebug.remote_mode              = "req"
xdebug.remote_port              = 9001
;xdebug.remote_timeout           = 200

;xdebug.show_error_trace         = 0
;xdebug.show_exception_trace     = 0
;xdebug.show_local_vars          = 0
;xdebug.show_mem_delta           = 0

; XDEBUG_PROFILE as GET/POST/COOKIE parameter
;xdebug.trace_enable_trigger     = off
; XDEBUG_PROFILE secret
;xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value = ""
; 0 - human readable, 1 - computer readable, 2 - HTML
;xdebug.trace_format             = 0
; 1 - append, 0 - overwrite
;xdebug.trace_options            = 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir          = "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/xdebug"
;xdebug.trace_output_name        = "trace.%c"

;xdebug.var_display_max_children = 128
;xdebug.var_display_max_data     = 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    = 10
```

Comment: Попробуй тут посмотреть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482 .... возможно порт будет да не 9001 а 9001 - но там рабочий вариант........ плюс ты напиши как ты дебаг устанавливал, винда или линукс, сколько версий у тебя на компе? может там под конкретную версию надо настраивать  ............... тут примерно тоже самое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480402/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский винда 10-ка х64. Дебаг у меня в комплекте с ОпенСервером был + расширение в хроме стоит,я так понял это очень индивидуальная штука - его настройка,так что бубен в руки беру и буду продолжать пробовать

Comment: На OS должно быть всё настроено уже. Там никаких шаманств не нужно.... ЗЫ: никакие расширения для браузера не нужны тоже уже лет 10........

Comment: Для того чтобы посмотреть есть ли xdebug надо посмотреть phpinfo()...... В целом, может ты не так что-то в ide делаешь, например в phpstorm не включил прослушивание

Comment: Пользуюсь vsCode.Дебагер установлен и видит его корректно,пересмотрил 100500 тутториалов,но дебагер не работает совсем